# SQL Developer will not start on Linux Fedora 29

Tags: linux, oracle-sqldeveloper, fedora-28

After a recent `dnf update` to Fedora 28, Oracle SQL Developer fails to start.

When I run it with `/usr/local/bin/sqldeveloper` there is a brief white flash (which I believe is the opening flash box), but the GUI does not display, and the program exits, leaving behind no running process.

The following is shown when I run

```
   /opt/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper.sh --verbose

20:42:01 Launching IDE

 Oracle SQL Developer
 Copyright (c) 2005, 2018, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

20:42:01 LAST_PWD_MADE_RELATIVE=/opt/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper/bin
20:42:01 LAST_RELATIVE_PWD=
20:42:01 Reading configuration from: /opt/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper/bin/sqldeveloper.conf
20:42:01 Reading file ../../ide/bin/ide.conf
20:42:01 Computed new relative PWD: ../../ide/bin
20:42:01 Reading file ../../ide/bin/jdk.conf
20:42:01 Adding VM Option: -Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true
20:42:01 Adding VM Option: -XX:CompileCommand=quiet
20:42:01 Adding VM Option: -XX:CompileCommand=exclude,javax/swing/text/GlyphView,getBreakSpot
20:42:01 Done reading file ../../ide/bin/jdk.conf
20:42:01 Adding Java Lib File: ../../ide/lib/ide-boot.jar
20:42:01 Adding Java Lib File: ../../netbeans/platform/lib/boot.jar
20:42:01 Adding Java Lib File: ../../netbeans/platform/lib/org-openide-util-ui.jar
20:42:01 Adding Java Lib File: ../../netbeans/platform/lib/org-openide-util.jar
20:42:01 Adding Java Lib File: ../../netbeans/platform/lib/org-openide-util-lookup.jar
20:42:01 Adding Java Lib File: ../../netbeans/platform/lib/org-openide-modules.jar
20:42:01 Adding Java Lib File: ../../ide/lib/fcpboot.jar
20:42:01 Adding VM Option: -Dnetbeans.home=../../netbeans/platform/
20:42:01 Adding VM Option: -Dnetbeans.logger.console=true
20:42:01 Adding VM Option: -Dexcluded.modules=org.eclipse.osgi
20:42:01 Adding VM Option: -Dide.cluster.dirs=../../netbeans/fcpbridge/:../../netbeans/ide/:../../netbeans/../
20:42:01 Adding VM Option: -Xverify:none
20:42:01 Adding VM Option: -Doracle.ide.extension.HooksProcessingMode=LAZY
20:42:01 Adding VM Option: -Dorg.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator.configUrl=file:bundles.info
20:42:01 Adding VM Option: -Dosgi.bundles.defaultStartLevel=1
20:42:01 Adding VM Option: -Dosgi.configuration.cascaded=false
20:42:01 Adding VM Option: -Dosgi.noShutdown=true
20:42:01 Adding VM Option: -Dorg.osgi.framework.bootdelegation=*
20:42:01 Adding VM Option: -Dosgi.parentClassloader=app
20:42:01 Adding VM Option: -Dosgi.locking=none
20:42:01 Adding VM Option: -Dosgi.contextClassLoaderParent=app
20:42:01 Adding VM Option: -Dosgi.classloader.type=parallel
20:42:01 Adding VM Option: -Dosgi.bundlefile.limit=500
20:42:01 Adding VM Option: -Dide.feedback-server=ide.us.oracle.com
20:42:01 Adding Java Lib File: ../../ide/lib/xml-factory.jar
20:42:01 Adding VM Option: -Djavax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory=oracle.ide.xml.switchable.SwitchableTransformerFactory
20:42:01 Adding Java Lib File: ../../ide/lib/woodstox-core-asl-4.2.0.jar
20:42:01 Adding Java Lib File: ../../ide/lib/stax2-api-3.1.1.jar
20:42:01 Adding VM Option: -Djavax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory=com.ctc.wstx.stax.WstxInputFactory
20:42:01 Adding VM Option: -Djavax.xml.stream.util.XMLEventAllocator=oracle.ideimpl.xml.stream.XMLEventAllocatorImpl
20:42:01 Adding VM Option: -Doracle.ide.reportEDTViolations=bug
20:42:01 Adding VM Option: -Doracle.ide.reportEDTViolations.exceptionsfile=./swing-thread-violations.conf
20:42:01 Adding VM Option: -Xms128M
20:42:01 Adding VM Option: -Xmx800M
20:42:01 Adding VM Option: -Doracle.ide.IdeFrameworkCommandLineOptions=-clean,-console,-debugmode,-migrate,-migrate:,-nomigrate,-nonag,-nondebugmode,-noreopen,-nosplash,-role:,-su
20:42:01 Done reading file ../../ide/bin/ide.conf
20:42:01 SetJavaHome called: ../../jdk
20:42:01 Adding VM Option: -Dide.update.usage.servers=https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/sqldeveloper/usage.xml
20:42:01 Adding VM Option: -Doracle.ide.util.AddinPolicyUtils.OVERRIDE_FLAG=true
20:42:01 Adding VM Option: -Dsun.java2d.ddoffscreen=false
20:42:01 Adding VM Option: -Dwindows.shell.font.languages=
20:42:01 Adding VM Option: -Doracle.ide.startup.features=sqldeveloper
20:42:01 Adding Java Lib File: ../lib/oracle.sqldeveloper.homesupport.jar
20:42:01 Adding VM Option: -Doracle.ide.osgi.boot.api.OJStartupHook=oracle.dbtools.raptor.startup.HomeSupport
20:42:01 Adding VM Option: -Doracle.jdbc.mapDateToTimestamp=false
20:42:01 Adding VM Option: -Doracle.jdbc.autoCommitSpecCompliant=false
20:42:01 Adding VM Option: -Doracle.jdbc.useFetchSizeWithLongColumn=true
20:42:01 Adding VM Option: -Dsun.locale.formatasdefault=true
20:42:01 Adding VM Option: -Dorg.netbeans.CLIHandler.server=false
20:42:01 Adding VM Option: -Doracle.xdkjava.security.resolveEntityDefault=false
20:42:01 Reading file sqldeveloper-nondebug.conf
20:42:01 Adding VM Option: -Dide.AssertTracingDisabled=true
20:42:01 Adding VM Option: -Doracle.ide.util.AddinPolicyUtils.OVERRIDE_FLAG=true
20:42:01 Adding VM Option: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=logging.conf
20:42:01 Adding VM Option: -Dsqldev.debug=false
20:42:01 Adding VM Option: -Dsqldev.onsd=true
20:42:01 Done reading file sqldeveloper-nondebug.conf
20:42:01 Reading user configuration file from: /home/alexb/.sqldeveloper/18.1.0/product.conf
20:42:01 Reading file /home/alexb/.sqldeveloper/18.1.0/product.conf
20:42:01 Computed new relative PWD: ../../../../home/alexb/.sqldeveloper/18.1.0
20:42:01 SetJavaHome called: /usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_171
20:42:01 Adding VM Option: -Xmx800m
20:42:01 Done reading file /home/alexb/.sqldeveloper/18.1.0/product.conf
20:42:01 Adding VM Option: -Dide.conf="/opt/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper/bin/sqldeveloper.conf"
20:42:01 Adding VM Option: -Duser.conf="/home/alexb/.sqldeveloper/18.1.0/product.conf"
20:42:01 Adding VM Option: -Dtool.user.conf="/home/alexb/.sqldeveloper/18.1.0/sqldeveloper.conf"
20:42:01 Adding VM Option: -Dide.startingcwd="/opt/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper/bin"
20:42:01 Getting major version from /usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_171/release
20:42:01 Contents of /usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_171/release: JAVA_VERSION="1.8.0_171"
OS_NAME="Linux"
OS_VERSION="2.6"
OS_ARCH="amd64"
SOURCE=" .:b8458ce8c60c corba:646464235a81 deploy:d5ea2c363bd4 hotspot:a9ea8a48feca hotspot/make/closed:8733af9690c2 hotspot/src/closed:3ca2c7325652 install:e701641804d9 jaxp:228ec0c489c0 jaxws:b4c4143de246 jdk:07e8e63a872c jdk/make/closed:71cb7cc00de5 jdk/src/closed:689bf8600e57 langtools:f09944bba0b4 nashorn:04a4e73e879e"
BUILD_TYPE="commercial"
20:42:01 Found JAVA_VERSION property
20:42:01 Found Java major version: 1.8
20:42:01 Checking if bin/java AND jre/bin/java exist for /usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_171
20:42:01 Checking if bin/java AND jre/bin/java exist for /usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_171
20:42:01 Extracting minimum major Java version from 1.8
20:42:01 Found minimum major Java version 1.8
20:42:01 Major Java version of Java is 1.8, which is bigger than/equal to minimum major Java version 1.8
20:42:01 Found existing Java executable /usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_171/bin/java
20:42:01 Found acceptable Java executable /usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_171/bin/java
20:42:01 Adding VM Option: -Xms128m
20:42:01 Adding VM Option: -Xmx800m
20:42:01 Adding VM Option: -Xbootclasspath/p:../../ide/bin/../../rdbms/jlib/ojdi.jar
20:42:01 Working directory is /opt/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper/bin
20:42:01 Running Command: /usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_171/bin/java -Xbootclasspath/a:/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_171/lib/tools.jar:/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_171/lib/dt.jar  -Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true -XX:CompileCommand=quiet -XX:CompileCommand=exclude,javax/swing/text/GlyphView,getBreakSpot -Dnetbeans.home=../../ide/bin/../../netbeans/platform/ -Dnetbeans.logger.console=true -Dexcluded.modules=org.eclipse.osgi -Dide.cluster.dirs=../../ide/bin/../../netbeans/fcpbridge/:../../ide/bin/../../netbeans/ide/:../../ide/bin/../../netbeans/../ -Xverify:none -Doracle.ide.extension.HooksProcessingMode=LAZY -Dorg.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator.configUrl=file:bundles.info -Dosgi.bundles.defaultStartLevel=1 -Dosgi.configuration.cascaded=false -Dosgi.noShutdown=true -Dorg.osgi.framework.bootdelegation=* -Dosgi.parentClassloader=app -Dosgi.locking=none -Dosgi.contextClassLoaderParent=app -Dosgi.classloader.type=parallel -Dosgi.bundlefile.limit=500 -Dide.feedback-server=ide.us.oracle.com -Djavax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory=oracle.ide.xml.switchable.SwitchableTransformerFactory -Djavax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory=com.ctc.wstx.stax.WstxInputFactory -Djavax.xml.stream.util.XMLEventAllocator=oracle.ideimpl.xml.stream.XMLEventAllocatorImpl -Doracle.ide.reportEDTViolations=bug -Doracle.ide.reportEDTViolations.exceptionsfile=../../ide/bin/swing-thread-violations.conf -Xms128M -Xmx800M -Doracle.ide.IdeFrameworkCommandLineOptions=-clean,-console,-debugmode,-migrate,-migrate:,-nomigrate,-nonag,-nondebugmode,-noreopen,-nosplash,-role:,-su -Dide.update.usage.servers=https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/sqldeveloper/usage.xml -Doracle.ide.util.AddinPolicyUtils.OVERRIDE_FLAG=true -Dsun.java2d.ddoffscreen=false -Dwindows.shell.font.languages= -Doracle.ide.startup.features=sqldeveloper -Doracle.ide.osgi.boot.api.OJStartupHook=oracle.dbtools.raptor.startup.HomeSupport -Doracle.jdbc.mapDateToTimestamp=false -Doracle.jdbc.autoCommitSpecCompliant=false -Doracle.jdbc.useFetchSizeWithLongColumn=true -Dsun.locale.formatasdefault=true -Dorg.netbeans.CLIHandler.server=false -Doracle.xdkjava.security.resolveEntityDefault=false -Dide.AssertTracingDisabled=true -Doracle.ide.util.AddinPolicyUtils.OVERRIDE_FLAG=true -Djava.util.logging.config.file=logging.conf -Dsqldev.debug=false -Dsqldev.onsd=true -Xmx800m -Dide.conf="/opt/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper/bin/sqldeveloper.conf" -Duser.conf="/home/alexb/.sqldeveloper/18.1.0/product.conf" -Dtool.user.conf="/home/alexb/.sqldeveloper/18.1.0/sqldeveloper.conf" -Dide.startingcwd="/opt/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper/bin" -Xms128m -Xmx800m -Xbootclasspath/p:../../ide/bin/../../rdbms/jlib/ojdi.jar  -classpath ../../ide/bin/../../ide/lib/ide-boot.jar:../../ide/bin/../../netbeans/platform/lib/boot.jar:../../ide/bin/../../netbeans/platform/lib/org-openide-util-ui.jar:../../ide/bin/../../netbeans/platform/lib/org-openide-util.jar:../../ide/bin/../../netbeans/platform/lib/org-openide-util-lookup.jar:../../ide/bin/../../netbeans/platform/lib/org-openide-modules.jar:../../ide/bin/../../ide/lib/fcpboot.jar:../../ide/bin/../../ide/lib/xml-factory.jar:../../ide/bin/../../ide/lib/woodstox-core-asl-4.2.0.jar:../../ide/bin/../../ide/lib/stax2-api-3.1.1.jar:../lib/oracle.sqldeveloper.homesupport.jar oracle.ide.osgi.boot.OracleIdeLauncher
```

The application appears to return result code

```
+ local exitCode=245
+ '[' 245 = 245 ']'
```

and

```
+ exitCode=1
```

when I turn on tracing in the shell script:

```
+ EchoIfVerbose 'Running Command: /usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_171/bin/java -Xbootclasspath/a:/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_171/lib/tools.jar:/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_171/lib/dt.jar  -Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true' -XX:CompileCommand=quiet -XX:CompileCommand=exclude,javax/swing/text/GlyphView,getBreakSpot -Dnetbeans.home=../../ide/bin/../../netbeans/platform/ -Dnetbeans.logger.console=true -Dexcluded.modules=org.eclipse.osgi -Dide.cluster.dirs=../../ide/bin/../../netbeans/fcpbridge/:../../ide/bin/../../netbeans/ide/:../../ide/bin/../../netbeans/../ -Xverify:none -Doracle.ide.extension.HooksProcessingMode=LAZY -Dorg.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator.configUrl=file:bundles.info -Dosgi.bundles.defaultStartLevel=1 -Dosgi.configuration.cascaded=false -Dosgi.noShutdown=true '-Dorg.osgi.framework.bootdelegation=*' -Dosgi.parentClassloader=app -Dosgi.locking=none -Dosgi.contextClassLoaderParent=app -Dosgi.classloader.type=parallel -Dosgi.bundlefile.limit=500 -Dide.feedback-server=ide.us.oracle.com -Djavax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory=oracle.ide.xml.switchable.SwitchableTransformerFactory -Djavax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory=com.ctc.wstx.stax.WstxInputFactory -Djavax.xml.stream.util.XMLEventAllocator=oracle.ideimpl.xml.stream.XMLEventAllocatorImpl -Doracle.ide.reportEDTViolations=bug -Doracle.ide.reportEDTViolations.exceptionsfile=../../ide/bin/swing-thread-violations.conf -Xms128M -Xmx800M -Doracle.ide.IdeFrameworkCommandLineOptions=-clean,-console,-debugmode,-migrate,-migrate:,-nomigrate,-nonag,-nondebugmode,-noreopen,-nosplash,-role:,-su -Dide.update.usage.servers=https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/sqldeveloper/usage.xml -Doracle.ide.util.AddinPolicyUtils.OVERRIDE_FLAG=true -Dsun.java2d.ddoffscreen=false -Dwindows.shell.font.languages= -Doracle.ide.startup.features=sqldeveloper -Doracle.ide.osgi.boot.api.OJStartupHook=oracle.dbtools.raptor.startup.HomeSupport -Doracle.jdbc.mapDateToTimestamp=false -Doracle.jdbc.autoCommitSpecCompliant=false -Doracle.jdbc.useFetchSizeWithLongColumn=true -Dsun.locale.formatasdefault=true -Dorg.netbeans.CLIHandler.server=false -Doracle.xdkjava.security.resolveEntityDefault=false -Dide.AssertTracingDisabled=true -Doracle.ide.util.AddinPolicyUtils.OVERRIDE_FLAG=true -Djava.util.logging.config.file=logging.conf -Dsqldev.debug=false -Dsqldev.onsd=true -Xmx800m '-Dide.conf="/opt/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper/bin/sqldeveloper.conf"' '-Duser.conf="/home/alexb/.sqldeveloper/18.1.0/product.conf"' '-Dtool.user.conf="/home/alexb/.sqldeveloper/18.1.0/sqldeveloper.conf"' '-Dide.startingcwd="/opt/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper/bin"' -Xms128m -Xmx800m '-Xbootclasspath/p:../../ide/bin/../../rdbms/jlib/ojdi.jar  -classpath ../../ide/bin/../../ide/lib/ide-boot.jar:../../ide/bin/../../netbeans/platform/lib/boot.jar:../../ide/bin/../../netbeans/platform/lib/org-openide-util-ui.jar:../../ide/bin/../../netbeans/platform/lib/org-openide-util.jar:../../ide/bin/../../netbeans/platform/lib/org-openide-util-lookup.jar:../../ide/bin/../../netbeans/platform/lib/org-openide-modules.jar:../../ide/bin/../../ide/lib/fcpboot.jar:../../ide/bin/../../ide/lib/xml-factory.jar:../../ide/bin/../../ide/lib/woodstox-core-asl-4.2.0.jar:../../ide/bin/../../ide/lib/stax2-api-3.1.1.jar:../lib/oracle.sqldeveloper.homesupport.jar oracle.ide.osgi.boot.OracleIdeLauncher '
+ '[' -n '' ']'
+ local exitCode=245
+ '[' 245 = 245 ']'
+ /usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_171/bin/java -Xbootclasspath/a:/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_171/lib/tools.jar:/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_171/lib/dt.jar -Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true -XX:CompileCommand=quiet -XX:CompileCommand=exclude,javax/swing/text/GlyphView,getBreakSpot -Dnetbeans.home=../../ide/bin/../../netbeans/platform/ -Dnetbeans.logger.console=true -Dexcluded.modules=org.eclipse.osgi -Dide.cluster.dirs=../../ide/bin/../../netbeans/fcpbridge/:../../ide/bin/../../netbeans/ide/:../../ide/bin/../../netbeans/../ -Xverify:none -Doracle.ide.extension.HooksProcessingMode=LAZY -Dorg.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator.configUrl=file:bundles.info -Dosgi.bundles.defaultStartLevel=1 -Dosgi.configuration.cascaded=false -Dosgi.noShutdown=true '-Dorg.osgi.framework.bootdelegation=*' -Dosgi.parentClassloader=app -Dosgi.locking=none -Dosgi.contextClassLoaderParent=app -Dosgi.classloader.type=parallel -Dosgi.bundlefile.limit=500 -Dide.feedback-server=ide.us.oracle.com -Djavax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory=oracle.ide.xml.switchable.SwitchableTransformerFactory -Djavax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory=com.ctc.wstx.stax.WstxInputFactory -Djavax.xml.stream.util.XMLEventAllocator=oracle.ideimpl.xml.stream.XMLEventAllocatorImpl -Doracle.ide.reportEDTViolations=bug -Doracle.ide.reportEDTViolations.exceptionsfile=../../ide/bin/swing-thread-violations.conf -Xms128M -Xmx800M -Doracle.ide.IdeFrameworkCommandLineOptions=-clean,-console,-debugmode,-migrate,-migrate:,-nomigrate,-nonag,-nondebugmode,-noreopen,-nosplash,-role:,-su -Dide.update.usage.servers=https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/sqldeveloper/usage.xml -Doracle.ide.util.AddinPolicyUtils.OVERRIDE_FLAG=true -Dsun.java2d.ddoffscreen=false -Dwindows.shell.font.languages= -Doracle.ide.startup.features=sqldeveloper -Doracle.ide.osgi.boot.api.OJStartupHook=oracle.dbtools.raptor.startup.HomeSupport -Doracle.jdbc.mapDateToTimestamp=false -Doracle.jdbc.autoCommitSpecCompliant=false -Doracle.jdbc.useFetchSizeWithLongColumn=true -Dsun.locale.formatasdefault=true -Dorg.netbeans.CLIHandler.server=false -Doracle.xdkjava.security.resolveEntityDefault=false -Dide.AssertTracingDisabled=true -Doracle.ide.util.AddinPolicyUtils.OVERRIDE_FLAG=true -Djava.util.logging.config.file=logging.conf -Dsqldev.debug=false -Dsqldev.onsd=true -Xmx800m '-Dide.conf="/opt/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper/bin/sqldeveloper.conf"' '-Duser.conf="/home/alexb/.sqldeveloper/18.1.0/product.conf"' '-Dtool.user.conf="/home/alexb/.sqldeveloper/18.1.0/sqldeveloper.conf"' '-Dide.startingcwd="/opt/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper/bin"' -Xms128m -Xmx800m -Xbootclasspath/p:../../ide/bin/../../rdbms/jlib/ojdi.jar -classpath ../../ide/bin/../../ide/lib/ide-boot.jar:../../ide/bin/../../netbeans/platform/lib/boot.jar:../../ide/bin/../../netbeans/platform/lib/org-openide-util-ui.jar:../../ide/bin/../../netbeans/platform/lib/org-openide-util.jar:../../ide/bin/../../netbeans/platform/lib/org-openide-util-lookup.jar:../../ide/bin/../../netbeans/platform/lib/org-openide-modules.jar:../../ide/bin/../../ide/lib/fcpboot.jar:../../ide/bin/../../ide/lib/xml-factory.jar:../../ide/bin/../../ide/lib/woodstox-core-asl-4.2.0.jar:../../ide/bin/../../ide/lib/stax2-api-3.1.1.jar:../lib/oracle.sqldeveloper.homesupport.jar oracle.ide.osgi.boot.OracleIdeLauncher
**+ exitCode=1**
+ ProductCanRestart
+ '[' X = X ']'
+ return 1
+ CanRestart=1
+ '[' 1 = 0 ']'
+ '[' 1 = 245 ']'
+ return 1
+ set +x
```

These are my O/S details:

- Fedora 28 Desktop: KDE Plasma

  cat /etc/redhat-release 
  Fedora release 28 (Twenty Eight)

  uname -r
  4.17.14-202.fc28.x86_64

  which java
  /usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_171/bin/java

  java -version
  java version "1.8.0_171"

  echo $JAVA_HOME
  /usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_171

  echo $DESKTOP_SESSION
  plasma

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [Database Administrators Stack Exchange](http://dba.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1):

Two things.

1. are you sure the update was complete, ie you could also run

   def update --refresh
2. Check the actual version of java, is it the oracle java and not the openJDK.

Comment: This is what I have - it looks like Oracle Java...

`file /etc/alternatives/java /etc/alternatives/javac
/etc/alternatives/java:  symbolic link to /usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_171/bin/java
/etc/alternatives/javac: symbolic link to /usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_171/bin/javac`

`/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_171/bin/java -version
java version "1.8.0_171"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_171-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.171-b11, mixed mode)`

`/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_171/bin/javac -version
javac 1.8.0_171`

Ran the dnf update --refresh
No change.

Comment: I ran another `dnf update` and `dnf update --refresh` this morning, and now SQL Developer starts. But the issue cannot be reliably reproduced, and so it cannot be diagnosed and repeatably fixed...

Comment: weird.  Let us know.